# How can I pass through a JSON object using an intermediate API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have two web API 2 projects, one of them is acting as a proxy, one is an API.

The signature of my proxy is:

`public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetByCatId(string id)`

The proxy project calls my hidden api, like this:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(CatUrl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"GetCat/{id}");
```

This returns a JSON object, which I want to simply return to the caller.

Because c# knows that it's a JSON object, I have to parse it out into a JSON object (i.e. `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>`). However I want the proxy to be dumb and not care about types so I can't do this because it will try to JSON deserialize the object to a string and throw an exception.

If I grab the stream (`response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`), I can parse it out into a string, however if I return the string in a new response, it doesn't realise it's JSON anymore and simply returns a string rather than a JSON object (i.e. the response is something like `"{ content: "{ .... my json string all in one string ... }" }"` .

How can I pass through the JSON object while retaining the fact it's a JSON object?

Comment: You can read the json string, then convert the string to a dynamic object using the **JObject**  by doing something like this, 

     
    `string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            dynamic jsObj = JObject.Parse(json);`

Comment: if you want to return the json object coming with response  just do: `return ResponseMessage(response );`

Comment: The `ResponseMessage` method was the one I was looking for, if you reply as an answer I can mark it - I spent ages searching for a way to convert a `HttpResponseMessage` into an `IHttpActionResult` and that is the exact badger

Comment: @NibblyPig I posted the comment as answer. If you want someone to see  your comment, mention him with @+{Username} so that the one gets notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the json object coming with response just do:

```
return ResponseMessage(response);
```